# req.on listener callbacks get executed the last in Node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, event-listener

I have a JSON sent in a request body that should get manipulated. But the two req.ons, which write and end the data, get executed, as the command prompt shows, after the rest of the function in which they are in, so I don't get my JSON and the rest of the program throws error.

I'm familiar with asynchronocity but have no idea how to get these two straight:

```
   req.on('data', function(data){
    buffer += decoder.write(data);
    });
 
   req.on('end', function(data){
     buffer += decoder.end(data);
   })
```

Been there for four hours and haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `data` and `end` events are `asynchronous`.  That means they come some time later, long after you've registered the event handlers.  And, `.on()` is non-blocking so it registers the event handler and then immediately returns and code placed after your calls to `.on()` will execute right after the event handlers are installed.  The callbacks for those events will get called sometime in the future, if/when that event occurs.

Code that you want to run when all the data has been collected must be inserted into the `end` event handler or put in a function that you call from there.

---

Here's an analogy.  You go to a restaurant to eat, it's full and has a waiting list.

So, you give them your phone number and they say they will text you when your table is ready.  That's like you registering for the `data` event.

Meanwhile, you go walk down the street for awhile and window shop to kill some time.  That's the rest of your code after the `.on()` calls executing.   You run into a friend who says he wants to hang out after you're done with dinner.  He gives you his number and asks you to text him when you're done with dinner.  This is like when you register a handler for the `end` event.

You continue walking around downtown for awhile longer.  Then, sometime later, you receive the text message that your table is ready.  That's like the callback for the `data` event getting called to tell you there is data ready.

You eat dinner and when you finish dinner, you text your friend that you're done.  That's like the `end` event.

Notice that interwoven between these various events, other regular things get to run (walking around town, talking to your friend, eating dinner, etc...).  This is like your other code that runs while waiting for those events to get called.

Code that wants to run in very specific times such as when one of those events occurs, must be in the specific event handler for that event.

Comment: Thanks for the allegory, you did a great job. Is there any other way than refactor all the rest of the function into the 'end' callback?

Comment: @KarolisVinc.Jachimavicius - Yeah, just move that code into that callback.  Or put it in its own function and call that function from the event handler.  This is how event driven programming works in nodejs.

Comment: Solved it using async/await. Finally! Thank you for your help.